# Applying a function over columns of matrix using RcppArmadillo works but returns error when applied over rows

Tags: c++, rcpp, armadillo, rcpparmadillo

I coded a function `qSelectMbycol` in `Rcpp` that returns the `k`th largest element of each column in O(n) time. This function works OK. If I try to do the same but work over rows instead of columns (function `qSelectMbyrow`) it returns the error `"error: Mat::init(): requested size is not compatible with column vector layout"`. Anybody any thoughts what I am doing wrong? I saved this file as "`qselect.cpp`" :

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#define RCPP_ARMADILLO_RETURN_COLVEC_AS_VECTOR
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
using namespace arma;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec qSelectMbycol(arma::mat& M, const int k) {

  // ARGUMENTS
  // M: matrix for which we want to find the k-th largest elements of each column
  // k: k-th statistic to look up

  arma::mat Y(M.memptr(), M.n_rows, M.n_cols);
  // we apply over columns
  int c = M.n_cols;
  arma::vec out(c);
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < c; i++) {
      arma::vec y = Y.col(i);
      std::nth_element(y.begin(), y.begin() + k - 1, y.end());
      out(i) = y(k-1); // the k-th largest value of each column
  }

  return out;

}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec qSelectMbyrow(arma::mat& M, const int k) {

  // ARGUMENTS
  // M: matrix for which we want to find the k-th largest elements of each row
  // k: k-th statistic to look up

  arma::mat Y(M.memptr(), M.n_rows, M.n_cols);
  // we apply over rows
  int r = M.n_rows;
  arma::vec out(r);
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < r; i++) {
    arma::vec y = Y.row(i); // this line throws the error "error: Mat::init(): requested size is not compatible with column vector layout"
    std::nth_element(y.begin(), y.begin() + k - 1, y.end());
    out(i) = y(k-1); // should give k-th largest value of each row
  }

  return out;

}
```

Example:

```
n=500
p=100
set.seed(1)
M=matrix(rnorm(n, mean = 100, sd = 1),n,1)
library(Rcpp)
library(RcppArmadillo)
Rcpp::sourceCpp('qselect.cpp')
qSelectMbycol(M,5) # works OK
qSelectMbyrow(M,5) # throws error "error: Mat::init(): requested size is not compatible with column vector layout"
```

I also tried inserting

```
  typedef std::vector<double> stdvec;
```

and replacing the line setting vector `y` by

```
arma::vec y = arma::conv_to<stdvec>::from(Y.row(i));
```

in my `qSelectMbyrow` function and although the function then runs, it runs slowly compared to applying over columns, and also crashes my R session if I run it 100 times.

Comment: Have you tried changing `arma::vec y = Y.row(i);` to `arma::rowvec y = Y.row(i);`?

Comment: Ha thanks - that did the trick! You can post it as an answer if you like!

Comment: Glad it was that simple -- answer added

Comment: For more speed, you can omit the matrix copy done by `arma::mat Y(M.memptr(), M.n_rows, M.n_cols);` There is already a copy being made by `arma::rowvec y = Y.row(i);`

Comment: Ha thanks for letting me know - this indeed also works OK (also in combination with OpenMP) and is slightly faster!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that an `arma::vec` is actually an `arma::colvec` (see [the docs](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Col)). So, we can solve this issue by changing

```
arma::vec y = Y.row(i);
```

(which is incompatible because it thinks you want a matrix with one column but you're trying to give it a matrix with one row) to

```
arma::rowvec y = Y.row(i);
```